# How to structure these objects to easily index and flatten when multiple non-independent lists are involved?

Tags: arrays, r, lapply

For the sake of illustrating the problem at hand with a fully reproducible set of data, I have the following simplified objects:

```
set.seed(7)
animalL <- list(mittens=list(what='cat', paws=4), lassie=list(what='dog', paws=4))
timeL <- list(list(foo=rnorm(2)), list(foo=rnorm(2)), list(foo=rnorm(2)))
houseL <- list(houseA=list(zip=123, roomL=list(den='some:blueprint', den2='another:blueprint')), houseB=list(zip=456, roomL=list(cove='a:blueprint', cove2='oneMore:blueprint')))
```

So there is a list of animals, each with their own features and associated data. There is a list of "time periods" each of which again has various features associated to them (simplified here to just a numeric vector of size 2). Finally, there is a list of houses, each with a list of rooms of possibly different lengths. From this data, I am able to evaluate, over the aggregate of all those time periods, at each house, what each animals "experience" is like. I can only do so, however, after letting each animal, during each time period, hang out in every room of every house. For the latter I have this function:

```
evaluateHangOutInRoom <- function(animal, timePeriod, house, room) { 
    list(x=rnorm(1), y=rnorm(1)) 
}
```

In real life this function is very slow, so I need to run it in parallel. I have an internal library for this but its interface is only that of `lapply`. Suppose it is this:

```
fastLapply <- function(X, FUN) {
    #in reality this is massively distributed
    lapply(X, FUN)
}
```

I can try to do this by doing index math, something like this:

```
AA <- length(animalL)
TT <- length(timeL)
RR <- cumprod(lapply(houseL, function(house) length(house$roomL)))
fastLapply(1:(AA*TT*RR), function(idx) 0)
```

But it is error prone to back out from `idx` the arguments to the hangout function.

I can try to structure an array of each "scenario" I need to work on:

```
hangOutArgArray <- array('', dim=c(AA, TT, RR))
dimnames(hangOutArgArray)[[1]] <- as.list(animalL)
dimnames(hangOutArgArray)[[3]] <- as.list(names(unlist(lapply(houseL, function(house) lapply(house$roomL, function(room) NULL)), recursive=FALSE)))
```

where maybe something like `Map` over the array dimnames and the array itself can produce a flat list which I can easily restructure back to the array shape after - but this is nasty...

How can I flatten out these different cases to pass onto the fastLapply, so that I can take the flat output of the same length and easily restructure it back into an easy to work with multi-dimensional layout for subsequent processing? At the moment this is the aforementioned nasty (but working) approach:

```
argumentArray <- array('', dim=c(AA, TT, RR))
dimOneNames <- as.list(names(animalL))
dimThreeNames <- as.list(names(unlist(lapply(houseL, function(house) lapply(house$roomL, function(room) NULL)), recursive=FALSE)))
dimnames(argumentArray)[[1]] <- dimOneNames
dimnames(argumentArray)[[3]] <- dimThreeNames
invisible(lapply(dimOneNames, function(d1) lapply(1:TT, function(d2), lapply(dimThreeNames, function(d3) { argumentArray[d1, d2, d3] <<- paste(d1, d2, d3, sep=';')}))))

resultL <- fastLapply(argumentArray, function(argStr) {
    argV <- unlist(strsplit(argStr, ';', fixed=TRUE))
    animal  <- argV[1]
    timePrd <- timeL[[ as.integer(argV[2]) ]]
    house   <- houseL[[ unlist(strsplit(argV[3], '.', fixed=TRUE))[1] ]]
    room    <- house$roomL[[ unlist(strsplit(argV[3], '.', fixed=TRUE))[2] ]]
    evaluateHangOutInRoom(animal, timePrd, house, room)
})

resultArray <- array(resultL, dim=dim(argumentArray))
dimnames(resultArray) <- dimnames(argumentArray)
```

Comment: You want all combinations of `houseL`, `timeL`, and `animalL` in an easy to work with data structure?

Comment: That's easy to put in an array, but I want to apply an operation to an unrolled list of houseL x timeL x animalL x roomL and bring it those results back to an easy to work with representation..

Comment: Have you looked at `?relist`? By making a list relistable you can unlist it and then relist it.  It sounds like this may be what you are looking for?

Comment: `?grid.expand` may also be of some help. But I may be missing the question...

Comment: @IanWesley - had never heard of relist, looking at that. For grid.expand you mean expand.grid?

Comment: Yes, `expand.grid`

Comment: the purr package also has a lot of helpful functional programming tools including `map` But I don't know them well enough to be of much help- at least quickly.

Comment: I've added my current working approach as well to illustrate the goal.